# Pagespeed Insiqhts: Since the new PSI, It won't analyze my website - just runs for hours

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Since the switch to the new Pagespeed Insights, I haven't been able to get it to analyze my site. It just runs forever.

[image: What I see for hours]

I am not a programmer, I've managed to put this website together with wishes and scotch tape. Any advice would be appreciated. I know I can use GT Metrix as well but I'd like to know what's wrong.

If I'm asking in the wrong place, can you kindly direct me to where I can get some help?

My website is: https://agrandromance.com

Thanks.

Comment: https://web.dev/measure works for your site and uses the same engine. There are loads of factors that can stop a page completing correctly so it is hard for us to debug so the simplest answer is normally to use an alternative. Either that or Lighthouse in developer tools is also the same engine so would give you a very similar result and recommendations.

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is the 8.22 second server response time reported by web.dev/measure - this is very very **very** high and might be causing page speed insights to time out and isn't an error they have accounted for. I would look into the cause of that (normally a poorly optimised database query causes large response times so I would start there and also examine your server logs for errors etc.)